# Tree branching starting from specific character of node

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees

I am doing parse trees for propositional logic formulas and I want to have the branches of a tree start from the main connective. Notice that the branching starts at a specific character for each node. Here is an example of what I am looking for:

[image: Expected]

This was done using phantoms to demonstrate. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    parse tree/.style={for tree={s sep=3em, minimum size=1.5em}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
        parse tree
        [\phantom{ssssssssssssssssss}$\neg (\neg P \to (Q \lor R))$
            [\phantom{sssss}$\neg P \to (Q \lor R)$
                [\phantom{ss}$\neg P$ [$P$]]
                [$Q \lor R$
                    [$Q$]
                    [$R$]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I'm hoping a solution could include the Forest package, but I am fine with anything that is easy enough to use!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not an expert on `forest`, but what about smashing the size of part of the equations with `mathtools`? Like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\forestset{
    parse tree/.style={for tree={s sep=3em, minimum size=1.5em}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
        parse tree
        [$\neg\mathrlap{(\neg P \to (Q \lor R))}$
        [$\mathllap{\neg} \to \mathrlap{(Q \lor R)}$
        [$\neg \mathrlap{P}$ [$P$]]
                [$Q \lor R$
                    [$Q$]
                    [$R$]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

...the only problem could be the bounding box of the final box, which can (will) be wrong. If this is a feasible solution, you can use a macro:

```latex
\newcommand{\balancemath}[3]{\mathllap{#1} #2 \mathrlap{#3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{forest}
        parse tree
        [$\balancemath{}{\neg}{(\neg P \to (Q \lor R))}$
        [$\balancemath{\neg}{\to}{(Q \lor R)}$
        [$\balancemath{}{\neg}{P}$ [$P$]]
                [$Q \lor R$
                    [$Q$]
                    [$R$]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{center}
```

...to obtain the same result. If needed, the macro can be changed (not trivially) to have a phantom bounding box so that it encompasses the full formula.

Comment: This is great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this answer even if it does not address OP's main issue (starting the branch below the connective), because (i) it provides a solution for the same problem (logic parse trees) and (ii) I had it already developed for myself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
  declare toks={left}{},
  declare toks={right}{},
  declare boolean={paren}{false},
  formula as tree/.style={
    formula@as@tree,
    for tree={
      content format={\ensuremath{%
        \noexpand\color{lightgray}\forestoption{left}%
        \noexpand\color{black}\forestoption{content}%
        \noexpand\color{lightgray}\forestoption{right}%
        }},
    },
  },
  formula@as@tree/.style={
    % assuming unary or binary branching nodes
    delay={
      for descendants children-first={
        if n=1{
          if={n_children("!u")==1}{
            append content to parent,
          }{
            prepend content to parent,
          }
        }{
          append content to parent,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  prepend content to parent/.style={
    if paren={
      !u.+left/.process={OOOw3}{left}{content}{right}{(##1##2##3)},
    }{
      !u.+left/.process={OOOw3}{left}{content}{right}{##1##2##3},
    },
  },
  append content to parent/.style={
    if paren={
      !u.right+/.process={OOOw3}{left}{content}{right}{(##1##2##3)},      
    }{
      !u.right+/.process={OOOw3}{left}{content}{right}{##1##2##3},
    }
  }, 
}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest} formula as tree
  [\neg
    [\rightarrow,paren
      [\neg
        [P]
      ]
      [\vee,paren
        [Q]
        [R]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is excellent. Thanks for authoring the `forest` package!

Comment: Just a quick question, do you have a code indenter/formatter that can process the `forest` environment / `\forestset`, or do you indent by hand?

Comment: I'm using Emacs and I have patched the tex indenter to do that. I'm planning to upload the patch, but haven't gotten to it yet. I'm happy to send you the patch, though.

Comment: Sounds good. Could you please email it to me at jjhan@vassar.edu whenever it is convenient?

Comment: done that, hope you got it.